# Mocha Unit test involving knex transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, knex.js

I have below unit test

```
knex.transaction(function(trx) {
  wrapperobj.insertData(trx, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
     expect(result.rowCount).to.be.equal(2); //fails, rowcount is 1
     trx.rollback(new Error('rollback'));  
  })
})
.asCallback((err, result) = > {
  expect(err).to.match(/rollback/);
  done();
});
```

It prints 2 failings
1) Uncaught AssertionError: expected 1 to equal 2. This is what is expected. 
2) "after each" hook for ... Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

**How do I prevent second fail message.**

I can put try catch around like below, but doesnt look neat

```
knex.transaction(function(trx) {
  wrapperobj.insertData(trx, (err, res) => {
        try {
          expect(err).to.be.null;
          expect(result).not.to.be.empty;
          expect(result.rowCount).to.be.equal(2);
        }
        catch(err1) {
            done(err1);
        }
        trx.rollback(new Error('rollback'));
      })
      .asCallback((err, result) => done())
```

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the root of the problem, but you could increase the default timeout by adding the flag `--timeout 15000` when you run the `mocha` command to test, or more ideally in an `mocha.opts` config file; with whatever number of milliseconds you like (this sets it to 15000 or 15 seconds. From [the docs](https://mochajs.org/#mochaopts):

> -t, --timeout
>
> Specifies the test-case timeout, defaulting to 2 seconds. To override
> you may pass the timeout in milliseconds, or a value with the s suffix, ex: --timeout 2s or --timeout 2000 would be equivalent.